# Conditional Formatting with icon sets and relative referencing in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I was wondering if there is any way to use relative referencing with icon sets in excel.  Ideally I would like to lock the row whilst allowing the column to change as the column is copied and pasted across the worksheet (ex. D$3).  Excel is telling me that I'm not able to use relative referencing with icon sets.

for clarification, what I'm trying to do is apply an icon set based on the relation between the current day and the target date of a project to be completed.

-The cell will show a checkmark so long as there is at least a week before the target date or if the cell reads 100%.

-If there are less than 7 days between the target date and current date then it will show an exclamation mark.

-otherwise show an x when the current day is the same as the target date and the cell's value is not 100%

the code that is being used as a condition is:

```
=OR(TODAY()+7-$D$14,$D$12=100)
```

What I would like is something equivalent to:

```
=OR(TODAY()+7-D$14,D$12=100)
```

I just don't know how to go about doing that
thanks in advance

below is the formatting rule window:
[image: Formatting rule]

Comment: Am I not reading this right?  In your code sample, the first clause in the OR() doesn't evaluate to True or False, just a number. Did you leave something out?

Comment: I added the window for the formatting rule in the question now, hopefully this addresses your question.

Comment: I've added more info in the question on what the conditions for each icon are and what I am trying to achieve with this icon set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without `%` appearing in all cells the only way I can see to meet your requirement is to enter 100 in those cells to display tick and 100% and then format those specific cells #,###"%".

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to say here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say and I figured out that I had to use 1 instead of 100 earlier I just never updated that code block however, this isn't really addressing the issue of the relative references. My current idea is to write a macro that will manually change the address value.

Comment: I'm not sure how I'm going to address this.  It arose from switching the colored cells to icon sets to represent project progress because it was easier to read from the printer.  Now it's just become a thorn in my side.

Answer (score 0):

If others come across this issue, you can kind-of use relative referencing... at least this is faster than setting up the rule for each cell or column manually. First do one cell (you must only choose one cell), and use INDIRECT to reference the value, e.g. to relative reference a column value inside the conditional rule (or could use rows if needed, etc...):

```
=INDIRECT("R14C" & COLUMN(), FALSE)
```

or to convert impactblu's formula, you would type it like this:

```
=OR(TODAY()+7-INDIRECT("R14C" & COLUMN(), FALSE),INDIRECT("R12C" & COLUMN(), FALSE)=100)
```

Then simply copy the cell, and Paste Formatting to the rest of the cells you need the icon set or color scale to apply. If you relative reference both row and column, you must paste one cell at a time. If as in this example case formula I've mentioned above you only relative reference a column but row is absolute, you can then paste a whole column at a time.
There are other ways to speed this up, but you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I wrote a generic macro to enable icon comparison between two data sets and apply the whole lot to a range.

The main block of code is below, but you can see more detail on my website at http://davidoverton.com/blogs/doverton/archive/2017/02/04/how-to-use-office-conditional-formatting-to-put-in-icon-sets-comparing-a-range-of-cells-or-relative-references-as-office-calls-it.aspx

```
Sub CompareIcons()      
   'In this example it starts in cell Q202 and compares to the cell Q210 and does this for 5 rows and 9 columns.  The icons used at xl3Arrows and removes all other conditional formatting on the cells impacted.
    Call GenericIconComparison(Range("q202"), Range("q210"), 5, 9, xl3Arrows, False, False, True)   

'In this example it compares the range from Q202:Y206 to the cells starting in Q210, so in effect the same as the one above
    Call GenericIconComparison(Range("q202:Y206"), Range("q210"), 0, 0, xl3Arrows, False, False, True)  
 

'In this example it does the same as the others, except higher values get a downward arrow and lover values get a higher value
    Call GenericIconComparison(Range("q210"), Range("q202"), 5, 9, xl3Arrows, True, False, True) 
 
End Sub 

Below is the VBA code to implement everything I’ve spoken about.  It does what is says on the tin.
Sub GenericIconComparison(IconsTopleft As Range, CompareTopLeft As Range, Rows As Integer, Cols As Integer, Icons As XlIconSet, ReverseOrder As Boolean, ShowIconsOnly As Boolean, RemoveOtherCondFormatting As Boolean) 
' 
' Icon Comparisons for ranges 
' 
    
    'get column top left for from and too ranges 
    from_col_number = IconsTopleft.Column 
    to_col_number = CompareTopLeft.Column 
    'If a range is given, use that over rows and cols parameters 
    If IconsTopleft.Columns.Count > 1 Then Cols = IconsTopleft.Columns.Count 
    If IconsTopleft.Rows.Count > 1 Then Rows = IconsTopleft.Rows.Count 
    For i = 1 To Cols 
        'get Column letter for from cell 
        from_col = from_col_number + i - 1 
        If from_col > 26 Then 
            col = Chr(64 + Int((from_col - 1) / 26)) + Chr(64 + from_col - Int((from_col - 1) / 26) * 26) 
        Else 
            col = Chr(64 + from_col) 
        End If 
        'get Column letter for comparison cell 
        to_col = to_col_number + i - 1 
        If to_col > 26 Then 
            ToCol = Chr(64 + Int((to_col - 1) / 26)) + Chr(64 + to_col - Int((to_col - 1) / 26) * 26) 
        Else 
            ToCol = Chr(64 + to_col) 
        End If 
        
        'create the rules 
        For j = 1 To Rows 
            'select the cell 
            Range(col + Trim(j + IconsTopleft.Row - 1)).Select 
            'clear other formatting if desired 
            If RemoveOtherCondFormatting = True Then Selection.FormatConditions.Delete 
            'add the rule to compare to other cell 
            Selection.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition 
            Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority 
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1) 
                .ReverseOrder = ReverseOrder 
                .ShowIconOnly = ShowIconsOnly 
                .IconSet = ActiveWorkbook.IconSets(Icons) 
            End With 
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(2) 
                .Type = xlConditionValueNumber 
                .Value = "=$" + ToCol + "$" + Trim(j + CompareTopLeft.Row - 1) 
                .Operator = 7 
            End With 
            With Selection.FormatConditions(1).IconCriteria(3) 
                .Type = xlConditionValueNumber 
                .Value = "=$" + ToCol + "$" + Trim(j + CompareTopLeft.Row - 1) 
                .Operator = 5 
            End With 
        Next 
    Next 
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't work much with icon sets, but this sounds like a general Conditional Formatting question to me. Try:

1. Set up your Formatting Rule for just the first row or column. Make sure to leave the extra `$` out. (You've pretty much already done this)
2. Copy it.
3. Select the next row/column
4. Go to **Paste Special**->**Paste Format**

Does that work?

Comment: it says I can't use relative referencing so even if I take out the $ it'll toss me an error and won't proceed with the okay

Comment: I see what you're saying. I wouldn't have expected that limitation.

Comment: yea it caught me offguard seeing as the "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" rule allows relative referencing